# How to Configure Hibernate with Eclipse Galileo

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, configuration, annotations

Can someone tell me how to configure hibernate (Annotations) with Eclipse?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve, please elaborate

Answer (score 1):

To use hibernate annotations in Eclipse I just add a reference to the required jar (hibernate-annotations.jar).

You will also need the hibernate jar and the ejb3 jar (ejb3-persistence.jar)